# Approach to the multi client server with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, networking, tcp, threadpool

I'm creating a multi client server (IRC) in C++ using Qt lib. I'd like to know whether it's a good approach to the server architecture.

I'd like to avoid creating thread per connection, so I thought that I could have all client sockets in some kind of container and perform actions (like processing incoming packet) using ThreadPool.

My only concern is whether having sockets connected to the `SLOT` guarantees parallel client handling.

Code :

```
CServer::CServer(QObject *parent) : QTcpServer(parent)
{
        server = new QTcpServer(this);
        connect(server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(newConnection()));

        if(!server->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 6667)) 
            qDebug() << "Oh noes";
}

void CServer::newConnection(){
           add server->nextPendingConnection() to the container
}
```

Comment: Is there a question that you meant to ask here?

Comment: The question is whether clients will be handled parallel or in one by one.